# Confusion about the tensor product structure of a multi-fermion Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, fermions

I often see people study entanglement in fermionic systems. The setup is often like this. Suppose we have a 1d lattice of  $2L $ sites, which is divided into a left part and a right part, each with $L $ sites. We have in total $N$  (spinless, for simplicity) fermions on the lattice. People then talk about the von Neumann entropy of the left (or the right) sub-lattice.

I am confused because I am worrying about the fermionic sign here. For bosonic or fermionic systems, we do not have the troublesome fermionic sign, so we can say the full Hilbert space is a tensor product of the subspace of the left half-chain and that of the right half-chain. In these two cases, the Schmidt decomposition of the full wave function is well defined.

However, for fermions, because of the negative sign, it seems that the full Hilbert space is no longer a tensor product of those of the two halves.

To have a tensor product structure, we should have the following property,

$$ \hat{O}_B |\psi_A \rangle  \otimes |\psi_B \rangle = |\psi_A \rangle \otimes \hat{O}_B |\psi_B \rangle  ,$$

where $\hat{O}_B $ is an operator on sub-lattice B and $|\psi_A \rangle $, $|\psi_B\rangle  $ are wave functions of the two sub-lattices. This seems to be violated for fermions. For example, suppose we have 4 sites in total, and let $c_i^\dagger$ be the creation operator on site $i$. We define the Fock state ($n_i =0 $ or $1$)

$$ |n_1 n_2 n_3 n_4 \rangle = (c_1^\dagger)^{n_1}(c_2^\dagger)^{n_2}(c_3^\dagger)^{n_3}(c_4^\dagger)^{n_4}|vac\rangle = |n_1 n_2 \rangle \otimes |n_3 n_4 \rangle .   $$

Here we have the defined $|n_1 n_2 \rangle =  (c_1^\dagger)^{n_1}(c_2^\dagger)^{n_2} |vac\rangle $.

Now consider the action of $c_3$,

$$c_3 |n_1 n_2 n_3 n_4 \rangle = (-1)^{n_1+n_2} (c_1^\dagger)^{n_1}(c_2^\dagger)^{n_2}c_3 (c_3^\dagger)^{n_3}(c_4^\dagger)^{n_4}|vac\rangle = (-1)^{n_1+n_2} |n_1 n_2 \rangle \otimes c_3 |n_3 n_4 \rangle .  $$

We have an annoying factor of $(-1)^{n_1+n_2}$. This means $c_3$ is not a local operator on sub-region B. We do not have tensor product of hilbert spaces, and the prerequisite of the Schmidt decomposition is missing.

The question is then, If your total Hilbert space is not a tensor product, how do you make sense of the Schmidt decomposition of a total wave function, how do you define the reduced density matrix, how do you define the von Neumann entanglement entropy?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch   If your total Hilbert space is not a tensor product, how do you make sense of the Schmidt decomposition of a total wave function, how do you define the reduced density matrix, how do you define the von Neumann entanglement entropy?

Comment: This isn't a full answer to your question. There is a superselection rule for fermions that only allows states that are anti-symmetric under interchange of two fermions. The Hilbert space of such systems can be constructed by using a wedge product of Hilbert spaces instead of the tensor product, see:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.09074

Comment: Reduced density matrix and its entropy are clear, they do not depend on the other system. But the definition is potentially affected by the fact that you have fermions.

Comment: I think the point is the isomorphism $\mathcal F(H_1\oplus H_2)\cong \mathcal F(H_1)\otimes \mathcal F(H_2)$.